# Remove required attribute from Search Controller - Property of non-object

Tags: php, html, controller

I have just started learning the basics but I have a website. The installed theme is pre-made so it has all the required code. So here is my problem
I have a search form in my website which consists of 4 steps / selections. select location, select category, select the item nature (lost or found), enter keywords and hit enter.
Only one of them (Select category) is marked as "required" in front.blade.php

```
<select id="category_id" class="select2" name="category_id" required >
```

I also want to remove the required attribute from this selection as well. So if I simply remove the "required" word, it gives error in "SearchController.php"

> Trying to get property 'category' of non-object

```
$CategoryData = Category::find($category_id); 
        $Category =  $CategoryData->category;
        switch ($Category) {
            case "Books":
                $category  = 'books';
                break;
            case "Currency":
                $category  = 'currencies';
                break;
            case "Electronic devices / Home appliances":
                $category  = 'electronics';
                break;}
```

It has about 15 categories but I have mentioned only few. Basically it highlights this line

```
$Category =  $CategoryData->category;
```

I treid to remove these categories but error continued on different line and so on. When I removed all the coding lines giving error in "SearchController.php", it gave error of another Controller file.

What is shortest and simplest way to remove the required attribute from my form for selection of category? If I now remove it, What do I have to do to enable this again? But first thing is to remove the required attribute. I do not want to remove categories so if user want to choose any category, he should be able to choose it.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your `$CategoryData` variable is null and early return if so. The error that's occurring suggests that `$CategoryData` isn't an object.

What you can do is:

```php
$CategoryData = Category::find($category_id);

if (!$CategoryData) {
   return;
}

$Category =  $CategoryData->category;
```

Comment: I don't know how to check variable is null as i said earlier, i have just started. So can you please tell me how to do that. I have added your said code but it stucks and nothing displays when i click on search

Answer (score 0):

This means that one of the queries is returning `null` or the result you are looking for is returning `null`, so you check the status of the variables using `dd($CategoryData);` in your controller.

Comment: I added your said code dd($CategoryData); right before my above said code so now code looks like `dd($CategoryData);
        $CategoryData = Category::find($category_id);
        $Category =  $CategoryData->category;`
and when searched in form it says undefined variable.

Comment: so did you have before your code like this: `$category_id = $request->input('category_id');` to request  the input from the form? @shoaibshuja

Comment: Yes I have that line in my code/ here are the previous lines `public function Search(Request $request)
    {

        $latitude = $request->get('loc_lat');
        $longitude = $request->get('loc_long');

        $category_id = $request->get('category_id');

        $addType = $request->get('addType');

        $keyword = $request->get('keyword');`

Comment: please add `dd($category_id);` after you requested the input and let me know the result; @shoaibshuja

Comment: I have added the code just after ('category_id') like this `$category_id = $request->get ('category_id');
dd($CategoryData);
 
        $addType = $request->get('addType'); ` and now error says **Undefined variable: CategoryData**

Comment: not `dd($CategoryData);` i told you to add `dd($category_id);`

Comment: Sorry. Now I have replaced it with `dd($category_id);` and it says **null**

Comment: this is the problem, the category_id is null, so in the blade.php do you have a form with the route and submit button? @shoaibshuja

Comment: Can you please check view page source of this site milgya.org. you may find what you are asking.

Comment: if you add a static `$category_id = 1;` before this line `$CategoryData = Category::find($category_id);` and then  after this line do `dd($CategoryData);` then i think you will get a data. @shoaibshuja

Comment: After adding above codes. this gives error of `Category {#389 ▼
  #fillable: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "categories"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:6 [▶]
  #original: array:6 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}`

Comment: When I added `$category_id = 1;` before this line `$CategoryData = Category::find($category_id);` and then after this line do `dd($CategoryData);` , then it gave me the above error. I received the error if i delete the above added `dd($category_id);`. But if I don't delete `dd($category_id);` it says Null

Comment: this is not an error, this means the problem solved, you cant enter the route [link]https://milgya.org/Search without adding inputs to it like this route [link]https://milgya.org/Search?loc_lat=&loc_long=&category_id=11&addType=Lost&keyword=  then you must handle the error by adding that the category_id is required as a validation first like `request()->validate([ 'category_id' => 'required', ]);`

Comment: add  `try {
            $CategoryData = Category::find($category_id); 
        } catch (ErrorException $exception) {
            return back()->withErrors($exception)->withInput();
        }`

Comment: I gave you the link of live website. But I am working on Localhost. So you might have searched right. But I didn't get what it means. When I added the `$category_id = 1;` and `dd($CategoryData);` and then after saving file, I searched without entering the category name or id, It gave me the above long code which I pasted earlier and didn't give me the search result

Comment: @shoaibshuja see the problem is that you didn't handle the error, this is why when you enter the search without entering the category_id you will get the error trying to get property of nonobject since category_id is null, and I tried the website and see that this is the error, when you select the name of the category the search work correctly but if you add to the link https://milgya.org word Search like this https://milgya.org/Search and press enter then you will face the error that you faced this is why you didn't handle the error in your controller

Comment: if you need to answer the code I new answer in a clean way there is no problem :)